# bash functions. help me understand

Tags: bash, function, ls, cd

Trying to set up a shortcut that will allow me to cd into a directory and list the files within in one go

here is what I got so far.  My knowledge is limited, this is pretty much just copy and paste from sources online, don't know what I'm doing, but learning in the process:

```
cdl () {
    cd $1
    ls . $1
}
```

it does what I want, but produces an error:

```
ls: cannot access colorschemes/: No such file or directory
.:
```

how do I get rid of the error message?

Comment: Hint: When you `cd` into a directory called `dirname` does `ls dirname` still make sense?

Comment: if I take out the `.` from the 3rd line then I get this error 'ls: cannot access colorschemes/: No such file or directory' and doesn't list the files at all

Answer (score 2):

If you already CD to a directory, then there is no need to run nothing more than ls -lth. Its not necessary to mention the directory name again.

```
function cdl () {
   cd "$1"
   ls -lth
}
```

I recommend puttin this into your .bash_profile, if you are not already doing it.

Regards!

Comment: Should really quote `"$1"`.

Comment: nice one.  thank you.  does exactly what I want (minus the -lth flags).  can you explain why this works and mine didn't?  has it got something to do with the `function` before `cdl`?

Comment: @m147 Cool. Happy to hear that.

Comment: can you explain why this works and mine didn't? has it got something to do with the function before cdl?

Comment: @m147 You tried to list both `colorschemes/` and `colorschemes/colorschemes/`. The latter is an invalid directory, resulting in the error. It's not related to your function in any way. You will get the same error if you open a terminal, run `cd /` and then `cd tmp` to change to `/tmp` followed by `ls tmp` to try to list a directory `tmp` inside `/tmp`. The correct way to list the current directory is `ls` or `ls .`, not `ls relativeNameOfCurrentDir`

Comment: @thatotherguy does that have to do with the `.` or the `$1`?

Comment: @m147 That has to do with the `$1`.

Comment: @thatotherguy  nice one!  I tried it out in the .bash* files and it works.  thanks.  still don't quite understand how it all works but I'll figure it out.  anyway, I got all this from this site, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-useful-bash-aliases-and-function.  which does include the `$1` on the last line.  also, why quote the initial `$1` in the 2nd line in the above example?